# Migration to identity columns on PostgreSQL, but without privileges to modify pg_depend

Tags: postgresql, doctrine, dbal

On preparation to the release of Doctrine DBAL 4, I want to migrate the identity column of my autoincrement based tables to "serial" type columns, as described here:

[Migration to identity columns on PostgreSQL](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/how-to/postgresql-identity-migration.html)

There is a nice script included and everything.

The problem is that this script runs this:

```
-- change the dependency between column and sequence to internal
  UPDATE pg_depend
    SET deptype = 'i'
    WHERE (classid, objid, objsubid) = ('pg_class'::regclass, seqid, 0)
      AND deptype = 'a';
```

And since my db is hosted as managed database on DigitalOcean, my `doadmin` user doesn't have enough privileges to modify this table directly:

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for table pg_depend
> CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE pg_depend
>    SET deptype = 'i'
>    WHERE (classid, objid, objsubid) = ('pg_class'::regclass, seqid, 0)
>      AND deptype = 'a'"
> PL/pgSQL function upgrade_serial_to_identity(regclass,name) line 31 at SQL statement
> ```

How can I perform this migration, without having access to change this user's privileges or this table permissions?

Answer (score 2):

Modifying catalog tables like that is dangerous and likely to lead to data corruption. Why so complicated, if there is a fast and simple way to do it?

Given a table like this:

```
\d s
                            Table "laurenz.s"
 Column │  Type   │ Collation │ Nullable │            Default            
════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════════════
 id     │ integer │           │ not null │ nextval('s_id_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "s_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

The quick and clean way to switch to using an identity column is the following:

```
-- make the change atomic
BEGIN;

-- prevent concurrent access to the table
LOCK s;

-- get the current sequence value
SELECT last_value FROM s_id_seq;

 last_value 
════════════
       1000
(1 row)

-- get rid of the sequence
DROP SEQUENCE s_id_seq CASCADE;
NOTICE:  drop cascades to default value for column id of table s

-- turn "id" into an identity column, start the sequence a little higher
ALTER TABLE s ALTER id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START 1100);

-- done
COMMIT;
```

Now the table is fine:

```
\d s
                           Table "laurenz.s"
 Column │  Type   │ Collation │ Nullable │           Default            
════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪══════════════════════════════
 id     │ integer │           │ not null │ generated always as identity
Indexes:
    "s_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Nice. Since I'll have to perform this on multiple tables, it would be great to have it in the shape of a stored procedure that took table name + column name as parameters (similar to the one in the linked docs, but using this logic). Would you mind?

Comment: Regarding "why so complicated": out of ignorance. The Doctrine DBAL devs provided that script, and I thought it was correct. I don't know why they took that path instead of the one you suggest. Would you be able to hazard a guess?

Comment: I am not a code generator, sorry. I guess the authors of the article lacked understanding and like playing fast and loose.

Answer (score 0):

Using Laurenz's excellent advice in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77907216/22264550), I wrapped the whole thing into a function, so it's easier to update the couple dozens of tables in my applications.

Luckily the auto-increment ids were the minority!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION serial_to_identity(table_name text, column_name text)
    RETURNS void AS
$$
DECLARE
    -- will hold the max value found in the sequence
    max_id integer;

    -- sequence name
    seqence_name text := table_name || '_' || column_name || '_seq';
BEGIN

   
    EXECUTE format('LOCK %I;', table_name);

    -- get current maximum id
    EXECUTE format (
            'SELECT MAX(%I) FROM %I;',
            column_name,
            table_name
            ) INTO max_id;

    -- drop the sequence 
    EXECUTE format('DROP SEQUENCE IF EXISTS %I CASCADE;', seqence_name);

    -- alter table so it now uses an identity, instead of the previously seqence
    EXECUTE format (
            'ALTER TABLE %I ALTER COLUMN %I ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH %s)',
            table_name,
            column_name,
            max_id + 100
            );

END;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Now to update table `xxx`, with column `id` I just execute:

`select serial_to_identity('xxx', 'id')`.

Seems to be working.

Comment: Your function doesn't lock the table, concurrent INSERT's can still continue and have an impact on your MAX(%I) outcome.

Comment: Thanks! I thought that because of the way functions worked on Postgres, a lock was not necessary. I misread the atomicity of the functions as having an implicit lock. My bad.